Поиск и подстановка значения из БД в форму внесения данных
начинаю освоение связки Postgres + php + JS ( от него видимо никуда не деться) + bootstrap.
Вопрос скорее относится к стандартным и шаблонным, но второй день не могу его сформулировать и найти пример кода для вдохновения.
Буду благодарен опытным товарищам за пинок в нужную сторону.
В Postgres создана БД с двумя таблицами ( клиенты / заказы ) данные на страницу вроде бы выводятся из поиска в таблицу  / отправляются из формы ввода.
На данный момент форма создания заказа состоит из полей заполняемых вручную что не очень оптимально поскольку в процессе породит дубли например в наименовании клиента <ООО "Ромашка"> и <ООО Ромашка> следовательно значение в поле "клиент" необходимо добавлять из существующих значений ( из таблицы клиент, где средствами БД например по primary key ИНН избегаю дубликатов).
Аналогичным образом формируются поля заказа "товар" по ID.
В текущей концепции "дизайна" и "логики" формы заказа к полю "клиент" относится кнопка поиска при нажатии которой в модальном окне силами php по одному нескольким критериям например "название" или "инн" из таблицы "клиенты" в таблицу подгружается соответствующие критериям строки клиентов.
Далее чекбоксом / кнопкой "выбрать" данные выбранного клиента вносятся в основную форму запроса.
На данный момент это реализовано криво и супер костылем, когда результат поиска ( таблица с несколькими значениями) выводится ниже формы запроса и ID необходимого клиента нужно вручную скопипастить в форму запроса.
Как один из вариантов решения нашел использование JS Autocomplete с выборкой значений из таблицы "клиенты" и выводом как в поле как select, но хоть сервис сугубо для локального 5-6 человек максимум использования, что то мне подсказывает подобный метод тоже костыль и будет создавать излишнюю нагрузку на сервер БД и путь в никуда.
Подскажите пожалуйста возможное направление куда копать.
Насколько я понимаю решение выглядит как
JS кнопка открытия модального окна - тут понятно
поля поиска + таблица вывода данных из БД ( php + AJAX чтобы избежать перезагрузки основной страницы
кнопка "выбрать"/"добавить" - JS - закрытие модального окна + подстановка выбранного значение в поле формы "клиент"
PSS для наглядности набросал содержимое и логику окон кратко
1)Пользователь нажал кнопку <Найти в БД> в форме (1)
2)Открылось модальное окно (2)
3)По названию в таблицу выводится список клиентов из БД
4)Как подсказали ниже либо c помощью ClickOnRow либо чекбоксом выбирается нужная строка и данные из нее подставляются в форму (3)

Заполненная форма отправляется в БД.





Миллиард слов и ничего не ясно в этой мешанине в итоге.... Сформулируйте кратко и чётко: цель такая-то, куда копать.

Алексей, к сожалению багаж знаний в этой теме пока что не набрал, приходится быть излишне многословным, добавил краткое описание и "пример" интерфейса для наглядности, спасибо.

Чтобы выражаться чётко и по делу - не нужно иметь спец знаний и багажа по теме, это в принципе обычная способность человека. Вы же не набираетесь достаточного багажа знаний в теме навигации по городу и ориентированию на местности, чтобы таксисту сказать довезти до аэропорта? И не изучаете тему искусства выпечки хлебобулочных изделий, чтобы совершенно конкретизированно попросить пирожок с мясом в ларьке

Различные варианты, самые часто встречаемые вы описали.

Выбор в модальном окне из справочника

Есть кнопка, при клике на ней открывается модальное окно. Там таблица, где есть постраничная навигация, поля поиска и возможность выбрать запись. Чекбокс неудобен, лучше регистрировать клик на всю строчку целиком. Нажали выбрать, запросили данные с бека и подставили в форму нужные значения.

Выпадающий список с автозаполнением

Упомянутый Autocomplete один из них. Если переживаете за бек, есть несколько способов оптимизации. Запрашивать только когда введено не менее нескольких символов, если система позволяет и там нет одно- и двухбуквенных значений. Запрашивать только первые 10 совпадений, остальное по мере уточнения данных в текстовом поле.

Комбинированный подход, ничто не мешает иметь два вышеперечисленных способа ввода.

Можете допилить свой костыль, вам не хватает только по клику на строчке таблицы, копировать автоматом данные в форму. Есть еще такая вещь, как конструктор форм, где человек пошагово выбирает значения. Тоже один из вариантов.


Но в общем первых двух хватает под большинство задач, на сайтах вы только их и встретите. Готовые компоненты ищутся достаточно просто. Впрочем, вы уже подключили bootstrap, следовательно можете и его компоненты взять.

большое спасибо - за развернутый ответ и заданное направление поиска! Теперь стало значительно понятнее в каком направлении двигаться!
